# I want an image to change depending on where I choose to go

Tags: javascript, html, image, statements

So I'm making this text adventure game and basically you can type in a set of actions on where you'd like to go in this imaginary map. For example, type into an input box "north" and then the result will be, "you decided to go north and was greeted with a supermarket". What I'd like to know is, if it was possible if I could add in an image based on the destination I chose? Like the example above, I chose north and ended up at a supermarket so the result will be an image of a supermarket.
I've already figured out the works of the if statements displaying the text to let the player know where he went, but I'd also like to know how to add in an image along with it?

...

```
<p> Pick a direction to go </p>

<input id = "input" type = "text" placeholder = "Type Help for actions"/><button onClick = "button()">Confirm</button>
<p id = "message"></p>


<script>

  function button() {
    var textInput;
    var newInput = input.value;
    if (newInput == "North") {
      textInput = "you went to the Abandoned Church";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
    }

    if (newInput == "North Again") {
      textInput = "you went to the Abandoned Someplace";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
    }

    if (newInput == "Help") {
      textInput = "Commands you can use: <ul><li>South</li><li>North</li><li>East</li><li>West</li><li>North Again</li><li>South again</li><li>West Again</li><li>East Again</li><li>North One More</li><li>East Once More</li><li>West Once More</li><li>South Once More</li>";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
    }


  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, there are two ways you can do this.

#### Solution A - HTML/JS combination:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImg"/>

<p>Click the button to change the value of the src attribute of the image.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The src property can be changed at any time. However, the new image inherits the height and width attributes of the original image, if not new height and width properties are specified.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "hackanm.gif";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this approach, you have a prefined image tag in your html but it has no img src. You can set that at the time you want in your javascript - so ideally when they select a direction or option.

So in your case it would be like this:

```js
<p> Pick a direction to go </p>

<img id="myImg"/>

<input id = "input" type = "text" placeholder = "Type Help for actions"/><button onClick = "button()">Confirm</button>
<p id = "message"></p>


<script>

  function button() {
    var textInput;
    var newInput = input.value;
    if (newInput == "North") {
      textInput = "you went to the Abandoned Church";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
      document.getElementById("myImg").src = "church.png";
    }

    if (newInput == "North Again") {
      textInput = "you went to the Abandoned Someplace";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
      document.getElementById("myImg").src = "abandoned.png";
    }

    if (newInput == "Help") {
      textInput = "Commands you can use: <ul><li>South</li><li>North</li><li>East</li><li>West</li><li>North Again</li><li>South again</li><li>West Again</li><li>East Again</li><li>North One More</li><li>East Once More</li><li>West Once More</li><li>South Once More</li>";
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
    }


  }

</script>
```

#### Solution B - Purely JS:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to change the value of the src attribute of the image.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The src property can be changed at any time. However, the new image inherits the height and width attributes of the original image, if not new height and width properties are specified.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.id = "myImg";
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "hackanm.gif";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively with **Solution B**, you do not need to define the `<img/>` tag at all in your html and can create it from the javascript purely.

I suggest reading this document for more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_src2)

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For this, it would be better if you took a data-driven approach. If you have a set of data that you can query, you can retrieve anything you need including image URLs. Here's a simple example for your use case:

```
let data = {
      options: {
        North: {
          message: "you went to the Abandoned Church",
          image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1"
        },
        South: {
          message: "you went to the Abandoned Someplace",
          image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2"
        }
      }
    };
```

I've also created a Codepen for it here: https://codepen.io/richjava/pen/poJmKBg

I hope it helps.